# API authentication best practices

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

For a customer API allowing the customer to access their data I'm wondering what's the most reasonable way forward for authentication. Currently the API is based on OAuth 2.0 with authorization code flow but there are some challenges with it:

- Many customers have only limited/no knowledge of OAuth 2.0 and don't want to work into the standard. Also many customers have limited programming skills in general. They just want an easy solution to retrieve their data.
- The login flow via browser is considered unhandy.
- Refresh tokens expire at some point but customers don't want to sign in again.
- Tokens and endpoints are authentication-server specific. Incompatible changes require actions on client side including manual re-login. This makes authorization server vendor changes or just major updates difficult.

Recently I have frequently seen tokens as an easier means for authenticating:

- Within a web frontend an API token is created based on a user account. This token is valid until it is revoked.
- This token is passed to the server in some way via the authorization header.

Is this valid way forward? Are there any alternatives? Is it acceptable to renew the refresh token validity on each use so that a new login is never needed if the token is regularly used (and with this renewed)?

Answer (score 0):

Standards are created to help industry maintain high levels of interoperability and security. You can implement your own solution, but chances are it will not be as robust and secure as an OAuth flow. For example issuing a token which is valid until it is revoked, in my opinion, is a very bad practice. If someone manages to steal that token, they will be able to access your API for as long as you don't notice something odd is going on.

Your customers might want a simple solution, but it means it won't be secure.

If it's a problem for them to implement OAuth flows, maybe you should provide your own SDKs or libraries which will make it much easier for them to work with a flow. A library where they call a method `getToken`, and all the details are handled by your lib.

I also don't agree with the opinion that it's hard to change OAuth-compliant vendors. In most products you can easily change the paths for endpoints, and the parameters and flows are standardised. You are able to change an Authorization Server without your users ever noticing that (if you have standard compliant servers).

As for a rolling session, you can implement that. Whenever a refresh token is used to get a new access token you can issue a new refresh token with a prolonged expiration time. This way the refresh token can be valid indefinitely, as long as the user keeps using it.